# Generating text from scheduled task

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I currently write a PowerShell script for monitoring the scheduled tasks from the Windows task scheduler. I got everything to work except the description message for the triggers. I need the Windows generated text that is displayed in the task Scheduler. I can use C# or PowerShell to do this, but I haven't found a way to get this message and I have not enough time to write a generator myself.

Do you guys know a way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `Get-ScheduledTaskInfo`: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/get-scheduledtaskinfo?view=win10-ps)

Syntax:

```
Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
   [-TaskName] <String>
   [[-TaskPath] <String>]
   [-CimSession <CimSession[]>]
   [-ThrottleLimit <Int32>]
   [-AsJob]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Using the cmdlet without parameters will show all running scheduled task and their information.

Comment: When I use it without any parameters I get the following message: "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.". When I provide a Task Name it shows me not the information I searched (the triggers message)